# Add points to chart in C# that are variable

Tags: c#, charts

when I want to add a column to my chart by this way, it works:

```
ChartPartOneFrequency.Series["Part One Frequency"].Points.AddXY("0", 33)
```

but when I define a parameter as "int", it does not work and the chart changed to a bar shape

```
int y = 33;
`ChartPartOneFrequency.Series["Part One Frequency"].Points.AddXY("0", y)`
```

how can I give the chart a point that is variable?

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get a compiler error? If yes, which one?

Comment: No, I didn't get a compiler error. I got a chart which there is no column in it.

Comment: This is not possible! There must be other errors in your code. ChartType cannot change this way. Also: Always try to avoid x-values as strings! Note: You can't expect the chart to change its Points by later changing the variable! If that was the question the answer is: Not possible. But: You could create a Property and in its setter add code that updates the chart. But for this the points index must also be known!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. you should convert int to string! like this:

```
int y = 33;
ChartPartOneFrequency.Series["Part One Frequency"].Points.AddXY("0", y.ToString());
```

Comment: This is utter nonsense! You should most certainly not convert any value to string!! x-values as strings are pretty much useless and almost always need to be added as numbers. y-values are converted to doubles if at all possible and are zero otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `Points.AddXY(double, double)` overload, or `Points.Add(DataPoint)` method?